# Hibernate SchemaExport command line

Tags: hibernate

I found this documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/toolsetguide.html#toolsetguide-s1-3 saying that we can run SchemaExport using command line

```
java -cp hibernate_classpaths org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport options mapping_files
```

Can someone please provide an example of how this is used? What is the format of the classpath (perhaps a example classpath), how do I do it with a hbm.xml mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem :)
Example:

```
java -cp "hibernate/*" org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport --properties=hibernate.properties --text Person.hbm.xml User.hbm.xml
```

Here "hibernate/*" means that you have a folder named "hibernate" with all libraries for hibernate (incl. hibernate3 of course).

in my case:

- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- cglib-2.2.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-testing.jar
- hibernate3.jar
- javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar

You have to put in the current folder the file **hibernate.properties** (you can use **hibernate.cfg.xml**, but option will be --config instead of --properties. I.e. "--config=hibernate.cfg.xml")

--text - output to the console
Next a list of necessary files *.hbm.xml.

That's all.